# How to run a Flask app for App Platform locally in my venv?

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, digital-ocean-apps

I have a simple Flask app that runs on DigitalOcean App Platform with the run command: `gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --config gunicorn_config.py app:app`

I would like to test this locally in my virtual environment before pushing it to GitHub. What is the proper way to start the app locally with a python command (without messing up the way it runs on App Platform)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create venv:

   `python -m venv venv`
2. Activate venv:

   `source venv/bin/activate`
3. Install Flask:

   `pip install flask`
4. Create flask app in main.py (or use your own)

   ```
   from flask import Flask

   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route("/")
   def hello_world():
      return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
   ```
5. Run your app:

   ```
   set FLASK_APP=main # write your script name (my is main.py)
   flask run # * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
   ```
6. Open your browser on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

[More information in official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

here you go, i setup a flask postgres starter project for digital ocean app platform:

https://github.com/heyaustinwood/flask-do-app-platform

You can set it up and then run it locally first before you setup the project in digital ocean by following the steps in the readme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).